# Use the Extension method instead Built-in method in C#

Tags: c#

Some Built-in methods are not working for me, I' m using old version of .NetFramework for my application which is not having some new methods. So, I' m trying to create extension methods that overrides the built-in methods. But I' m facing some issues with. Here is the code:

```
using System; 
using System.IO; 
using System.Net;
using System.Xml;
using System.Text;  
using System.Collections.Generic;
namespace API{
public static class Retrive 
{               
    // some variables

    public static void CopyTo(this Stream input, Stream output)///Extension method
    {

        byte[] buffer = new byte[32768];  
        int read;

        while ((read = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            output.Write (buffer, 0, read);
        }
    }   

    public static void Main ()
    {
          string url = "https://";          
          string baseURL = "";   
          string authenticateStr = "";

        try 
        {
            ///
            }


        catch (WebException e) 
        {
            using (WebResponse response = e.Response) 
            {
                ////
            }
        }
    }  // end main()
}  // end class
```

}//end name space

The errors I' m getting are

> 1) Extension methods must be defined in a top level static class;
>   'Retrive' is a nested class .

I don' t understand why 'Retrieve' class became nested.

> 2) Extension methods must be defined in a non-Generic static class

How to solve these issues? Please help me.

Thank you.

Comment: I have the feeling we are missing parts of the codefile. Is that correct? Are you defining a namespace? And why did you move the Main-function from Program to Retrive? Is the Program-class actually removed?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. Your code does not compile, because of a type (character 's' between "responseText = sr.ReadToEnd();" and "List<string> uriList = new List<string>();
". Second, not all your namespaces are complete, because List<string> should use namespace System.Collection.Generic. Third, not all variables are declared, like "url" and "baseURL".
 and

Comment: if I am not mistaken your extension [will not be called](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx) as it has the same signature as [Stream.CopyTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.copyto.aspx)

Comment: I don' t need the Directives and namespaces to be defined, when I compile the code in my application the code gets decorated with the required Directives and namespaces. So, I missed namespace. Now I added namespace to the code.

Comment: But I' m facing issues with the class structure, AS I mentioned in the question.

Comment: Based on the errors you're reporting, it seems we're not looking at your whole code.  I don't see any other way to get the errors you're seeing.

Answer (score 0):

non generic static class means you are creating a class that is not using template.

e.g. List is a generic class but MemoryStream or alot of class are not generic.

nested class answer is already given in this thread.

Answer (score -1):

Try keeping "static void Main()" in any other class. I mean other than the one you are trying to use for creating extensions.

Comment: Yes, it is recommanded to seperate them, but since both Main and CopyTo can co-exist in the same static class, this is no way an answer to the question.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like your main methods is also in the Retriev class. I recommand to create a seperate class for extensions methods as shown below:

```
public static class ExtMethods 
{
  public static void CopyTo(this Stream input, Stream output)///Extension method
  {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[32768];  
    int read;
    while ((read = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
    {
       output.Write (buffer, 0, read);
    }
  }  
}
```

Comment: Yes, it is recommanded to seperate them, but since both Main and CopyTo can co-exist in the same static class, this is no way an answer to the question.